# 'ChemoSpec' package in R not working on mac OS X

Tags: r, macos

I'm trying to install an R package called ChemoSpec and am receiving the following error:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:   call:
>   dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)   error: unable to load shared
>   object
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so,
>   6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
>   Reason: image not found Error: package or namespace load failed for
>   ‘ChemoSpec’

I'm running R version 3.3 using R Studio on OS X 10.10.5

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I am the author of `ChemoSpec`.  The problem you are seeing is due to some combination of missing `X11` and/or `rgl`.  `X11` used to come with Macs but now must be installed separately.  You can get it [here](https://www.xquartz.org/).  Then try (in `R`) `install.packages("rgl")` and then try `ChemoSpec` again.  If you are not successful, e-mail me directly.

Comment: Very impressed with the fast and effective response. Seems to be working! Cheers Bryan.

Comment: +1 for the followup. The value of this information would be enhanced (and Jones rep increased) if one of the two of you should post an answer and then Jones could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly that you do not have `X11` installed.  This in turn prevents `rgl` from installing, and in turn, `ChemoSpec`.  Macs used to ship with `X11` installed, but since OSX 10.6 they have not ([info](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341)).  You can install `X11` from [here](https://www.xquartz.org/).  After that, try:

```
install.packages("rgl")
```

and if that is successful, do:

```
install.packages("ChemoSpec")
```

and you should be ready to go.